# {Updated} OfficeWriter error: the datasource binding name must be unique

Tags: c#, console-application, officewriter

**[SOLVED]** Faced this error when debugging, the error goes like this:

> Error attempting to interpret or access data field for the GetColumnNumber(Name) in row 0 of this data source
>
> This field name or index cannot be accessed for the datamarker <%%=Production.ProductID>
>
> **Solution: datamarkers replaced from %%=Production.ProductID to %%=$Production**

***[UPDATED]***
@AlisonB has been a great help once again on the error. Can now debug it but it show another error like this:

> All the datasource must be unique. The name 'Production' and worksheet" is already in use for a data source.

How will I use a name to put in XLT.BindCellData(), beside either reader or IdSQL? Because if I use reader, I will have this error. Same goes for the IdSQL too. But if I remove the while statement, it can debug but the excel file will show as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader in all the cells instead of the actual data.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExcelTemplate XLT = new ExcelTemplate();
        XLT.Open(@"C:\Users\administrator.EBSDLAB\Desktop\Examples\Test_DB\test.xlsx");
        DataBindingProperties dataProps = XLT.CreateDataBindingProperties();

        var strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Production"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        string IdSQL = "SELECT Name, Size, Color FROM Production.Product";
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(IdSQL, sqlCon);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            XLT.BindCellData(IdSQL, "Production", dataProps);
        }

        XLT.BindCellData(reader, "Production", dataProps);
        XLT.Process();
        XLT.Save(@"C:\Users\administrator.EBSDLAB\Desktop\Examples\Test_DB\products.xlsx");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in your template file is not compatible with the data binding call you are making in your code.

[BindCellData](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.BindCellData%28Object,+String,+DataBindingProperties%29) is intended to bind a single variable value to a cell. The parameters of *BindCellData* are an *Object*, which is the single value that you want to import, a *String*, which is the name of the data marker, and a *DataBindingProperties* object to customize how you want the data imported.

The corresponding data marker syntax for this method call is %%=$DataMarkerName, where "DataMarkerName" is the value passed to *BindCellData*. To match with the code that you posted, your data marker would be:

```
ProductID: %%=$Production
```

You can also change the method call you are making to match the the arrangement of the data markers in your template; the method call you need in this case is [BindRowData](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.BindRowData).

*BindRowData* takes a single row of values and imports them to the data markers, regardless of whether the data markers are in the same row or another configuration in the template file. You need a data marker for every column of data in your data source, which you already have done.

For more information about data marker syntax, please see our documentation on [Creating Data Markers](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Creating+Data+Markers). We also have a guide about using [arrays as data sources in ExcelTemplate](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Using+an+Array+as+a+Data+Source) and [importing database information](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Using+a+Database+as+a+Data+Source), if you are interested.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the datamarkers and it worked! But how will I use an unique name for the datasource binding? I have posted the updated coding up. Once again thank you!

Comment: The BindCellData method is meant to be called only once for each individual data source, so the name will always be unique.  BindCellData imports one value into a single cell in the workbook.  If you want to import multiple values into a row or column, or multiple rows of data into multiple rows in the spreadsheet, you should use different data binding methods (i.e. BindRowData or BindData).  Could you please explain more clearly what you are trying to do?